# Undefined behaviour while loading a large CSV concurrently using Goroutines

Tags: csv, go, goroutine

I am trying to load a big CSV file using goroutines using Golang. The dimension of the csv is (254882, 100). But using my goroutines when I am parsing the csv and storing it into an 2D list, I am getting rows lesser than 254882 and the number is varying for each run. I feel it is happening due goroutines but can't seem to point the reason. Can anyone please help me. I am also new in Golang. Here is my code below

```
func loadCSV(csvFile string) (*[][]float64, error) {
    startTime := time.Now()
    var dataset [][]float64
    f, err := os.Open(csvFile)
    if err != nil {
        return &dataset, err
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(f))
    counter := 0
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if counter != 0 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(r []string, dataset *[][]float64) {
                var temp []float64
                for _, each := range record {
                    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(each, 64)
                    if err == nil {
                        temp = append(temp, f)
                    }
                }
                *dataset = append(*dataset, temp)
                wg.Done()
            }(record, &dataset)
        }
        counter++
    }
    wg.Wait()
    duration := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
    log.Printf("Loaded %d rows in %v seconds", counter, duration)
    return &dataset, nil
}
```

And my main function looks like the following

```
func main() {
    // runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    dataset, err := loadCSV("AvgW2V_train.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(*dataset))
}
```

If anyone needs to download the CSV too, then click the link below (485 MB)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G4Nw6JyeC-i0R1exWp5BtRtGM1Fwyelm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is no need to use `*[][]float64`, `[][]float64` would be fine

Comment: @nilsocket For groutine inside anonymous function, you need to pass the pointer but from `loadCSV` function you can remove the pointer. But this doesn't change the error

Comment: I'm looking into it, do you need your data to be ordered, 2nd row, 3rd row ... as dataset[2], dataset[3], if that is the case it would be hard.

Comment: @nilsocket No I don't need that...In one answer it was told that the code has racing condition. Can you please tell me how to fix it. I used wait group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `*[][]float64` as that would be a double pointer.

I have made some minor modifications to your program.

`dataset` is available to new goroutine, since it's declared in it's above block of code.

Similarly `record` is also available, but since `record` variable, is changing from time to time, we need to pass it to new goroutine.

While there is no need to pass `dataset`, as it is not changing and that is what we want, so that we can append temp to `dataset`.

But race condition happens when multiple goroutines are trying to append to same variable, i.e., multiple goroutines are trying to write to same variable.

So we need to make sure that only one can goroutine can add at any instance of time.
So we use a lock to make appending sequential.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

func loadCSV(csvFile string) [][]float64 {
    var dataset [][]float64

    f, _ := os.Open(csvFile)

    r := csv.NewReader(f)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    l := new(sync.Mutex) // lock

    for record, err := r.Read(); err == nil; record, err = r.Read() {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(record []string) {
            defer wg.Done()

            var temp []float64
            for _, each := range record {
                if f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(each, 64); err == nil {
                    temp = append(temp, f)
                }
            }
            l.Lock() // lock before writing
            dataset = append(dataset, temp) // write
            l.Unlock() // unlock

        }(record)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    return dataset
}

func main() {
    dataset := loadCSV("train.csv")
    fmt.Println(len(dataset))
}
```

Some errors were not handled to make it minimal, but you should handle errors.

Comment: Thanks @nilsocket I previously thought that Waitgroup along with preventing synchronisation, removes any datarace too as all the goroutines are running synchronously. But now I see the flaw in my though...:)

Answer (score 6):

Go [Data Race Detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html)

---

Your results are undefined because you have data races.

```
~/gopath/src$ go run -race racer.go
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c00008a060 by goroutine 6:
  runtime.mapassign_faststr()
      /home/peter/go/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:202 +0x0
  main.main.func2()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:16 +0x6a

Previous write at 0x00c00008a060 by goroutine 5:
  runtime.mapassign_faststr()
      /home/peter/go/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:202 +0x0
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:11 +0x6a

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:14 +0x88

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:9 +0x5b
==================
fatal error: concurrent map writes
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c00009a088 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func2()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:16 +0x7f

Previous write at 0x00c00009a088 by goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:11 +0x7f

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:14 +0x88

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:9 +0x5b
==================

goroutine 34 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x49e156, 0x15)
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72 fp=0xc000094718 sp=0xc0000946e8 pc=0x44b342
runtime.mapassign_faststr(0x48ace0, 0xc00008a060, 0x49c9c3, 0x8, 0xc00009a088)
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/map_faststr.go:211 +0x46c fp=0xc000094790 sp=0xc000094718 pc=0x43598c
main.main.func1(0x49c9c3, 0x8)
    /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:11 +0x6b fp=0xc0000947d0 sp=0xc000094790 pc=0x47ac6b
runtime.goexit()
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1340 +0x1 fp=0xc0000947d8 sp=0xc0000947d0 pc=0x473061
created by main.main
    /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:9 +0x5c

goroutine 1 [sleep]:
time.Sleep(0x5f5e100)
    /home/peter/go/src/runtime/time.go:105 +0x14a
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:19 +0x96

goroutine 35 [runnable]:
main.main.func2(0x49c9c3, 0x8)
    /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:16 +0x6b
created by main.main
    /home/peter/gopath/src/racer.go:14 +0x89
exit status 2
~/gopath/src$
```

`racer.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func loadCSV(csvFile string) (*[][]float64, error) {
    startTime := time.Now()
    var dataset [][]float64
    f, err := os.Open(csvFile)
    if err != nil {
        return &dataset, err
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(f))
    counter := 0
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if counter != 0 {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(r []string, dataset *[][]float64) {
                var temp []float64
                for _, each := range record {
                    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(each, 64)
                    if err == nil {
                        temp = append(temp, f)
                    }
                }
                *dataset = append(*dataset, temp)
                wg.Done()
            }(record, &dataset)
        }
        counter++
    }
    wg.Wait()
    duration := time.Now().Sub(startTime)
    log.Printf("Loaded %d rows in %v seconds", counter, duration)
    return &dataset, nil
}

func main() {
    // runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    dataset, err := loadCSV("/home/peter/AvgW2V_train.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(*dataset))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter but I used waitgroup to synchronise. Can you please let me know how to fix it.??

Comment: @MayukhSarkar using waitgroup doesn't solve the data race issue. On solution is using mutex (locking mechanism) to prevent data race